# How to handle entities that is dividied in 2 entiries in dialogflow?

Tags: actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I have a phrases like

```
"Suggest me some good name for my son"
"Suggest me some good name for my daughter"
```

I have created 2 entities one is male and one female. I divide them in 2 entities. Now I want to handle both entities. Should I make 2 phrases everywhere for both gender or there is a way so I can simply write my one phrases that will help me from duplicate phrases.

I need to know in my code where someone is talking about a Female and Male. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a [composite entity](https://dialogflow.com/docs/entities#dev_composite) `Gender`, which groups `Male` & `Female`

Then in your intent you create a `Template Mode` training phrase

```
@ Suggest me some good name for my @Gender:Gender
```

And when you input

```
Suggest me some good name for my daughter
```

You will get `Gender` as parameter instead.

```
Gender.Female = 'daughter'
```

And `Gender.Male = 'son`' if you use `son`

> I need to know in my code where someone is talking about a Female and
>   Male. Thanks

**Javascript example**

```
const parameters = result.parameters;

if(parameters.Gender && !!parameters.Gender.Female)
   console.log('Female');
else if(parameters.Gender && !!parameters.Gender.Male)
   console.log('Male');
```

---

### Alternative without composite entity

Create a `Gender` (or whatever you like) entity, with 2 values: `male` & `female` with as many synonyms as you can.

```
male, male, boy, son, sons
female, female, girl, daughter, daughters
```

[image: https://i.imgur.com/AgnR9pp.png]

And now using the same `Template Mode` training phrase, you will get a parameter: `Gender` with `female` or `male` as value.

Comment: Does this need to be a composite entity? I think a new entity type will be sufficient, if I understand the OP.

Comment: @Prisoner added an alternative without composite entity.

Comment: @MarcosCasagrande thanks for answer, Give me sometime,  I am checking it.